# Firebase Tasks whenAll not working as expected, skipping OnCompleteListener

Tags: android, firebase, task, firebase-storage, android-task

This is the flow of  my program:

1. I can create a learning session where in this session, user can stream video, and/or download attached file(s), and/or answering question in multiple choice format.
2. So in one session, it can contains a video and/or file(s) and/or question(s).
3. In the process of creating session, I must finish all upload task for video and/or file(s) and also finish all database task saving the question(s) for that session, before I save the session in database. In this case, I use something like this `Tasks.whenAll(listTask)`, where I add `onCompleteListener` to the final task, where I finally save the session to database.
4. Almost all is working as expected, question(s) saved, video uploaded, but there is a problem with the `UploadTask` that returned from uploading the video. In my `Session` class, I have `videoUrl` field that will contain the url of the video. In order to get the url of the video, I must add `onCompleteListener` to my `UploadTask`, get the url from task's result and save the url in my class instance. But, the video url is never saved to database, because the `onCompleteListener` of final task is called first.

My question is, how to execute Tasks.whenAll(listTask), when all task in listTask are completed, with their onCompleteListener completed too?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Why do you want to execute `Tasks.whenAll(listTask)` after all tasks are complete?  That call itself returns a Task that's completed when all the tasks are also complete.